# Equivalent of Bind<>.ToMethod in Unity?

Tags: unity-container, ninject

Is there an equivalent of Ninject Factory Methods in Unity? I'm looking for the unity equivalent of the following example:

```
Bind<IWeapon>().ToMethod(context => new Sword());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the InjectionFactory:

```
container.RegisterType<IWeapon>(
    new InjectionFactory(con => new Sword());
```

Of course, I wouldn't use it in this particular case since the default behavior of the container would accomplish this with a simple type mapping. I assume your actual delegates are a bit more complex.

Comment: Indeed, this case will be used to cover non default initializing - Thanks!

Comment: I like to think that the OP is creating an application to build Swords so that's his exact delegate, much more interesting I'm sure...